# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline workspace limit

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

It seems that a Multibranch Pipeline job stores 20 workspaces and recycles them when new branches get pulled. Is there a way to limit it to 10 for example?

The problem with this limit for my project consumes all the inodes on disk with the node_modules so limiting the number of workspaces will help at least partially fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is inodes needing to be freed up, you could use:

```
deleteDir()
```

at the end of the pipeline, to recursively delete all files in the current workspace.